# Get own IP Address of Esp32 Device

Tags: sockets, tcp, esp32, micropython

I have an Esp32 function as a TCP socket receiver/server.

Probably can't always set a static IP on the device
so I'm looking to find out:

1. How can I get the local IP address from the Esp32 by using micropython.
2. Alternatively, I imagine it should be possible to scan for devices from the client side?
   The client Side is running on Python 2.7 ... so maybe you can give me tips on how to approach this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The micropython documentation includes information [about retrieving your network configuration](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/network.html). Have you tried that?

Comment: I havent tried anything yet ... because I dont know how to aproach this

Comment: Hopefully that documentation provided some ideas?

Comment: Reading the documentation is always a good way to approach things.

Comment: Client is running Python 2. , that client is in need of an upgrade, or [watch the sun set](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)

Answer (score 0):

From the Micropython documentation for PybD V 1.13, but common to most, if not all, ports..

```
WLAN.ifconfig([(ip, subnet, gateway, dns)])
Get/set IP-level network interface parameters: IP address, subnet mask,
gateway and DNS server. 
When called with no arguments, this method returns a 4-tuple with the above 
information. 
To set the above values, pass a 4-tuple with the required information, for example:

nic.ifconfig(('192.168.0.4', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.0.1', '8.8.8.8'))
```

Always a good idea to check documentation first as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

pehaps the use of a host name will help your client connect to the device as well.
so rather than hardcoding '10.1.2.3' you can connect from your client to 'mydevice.local'

something like the below should go a long way to ease that.

```py
import network
from config import homenet, CLIENT_ID

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)

    if not wlan.active():
        wlan.active(True)
    if not wlan.isconnected():
        wlan.config(dhcp_hostname=CLIENT_ID)
        log.info("Activating Wlan {0}".format(homenet['SSID']))
        wlan.connect(homenet['SSID'], homenet['password'])
```

config.py

```py
from  ubinascii import  hexlify
# Base SSID to connect to
homenet = {'SSID': 'ThisIsHome', 'password': 'MicroPython'}

CLIENT_ID = b'mydevice' #  + hexlify(unique_id())[-6:]
```